# How to register a type with autofac after container creation

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, registration, autofac

I have an infrastructure singleton that I would like resolved out of autofac

At container creation I register `AppPaths` as a singleton

However, for a variety of reasons (testing, a few infrastructure things) I would like to be able to swap that instance out with a new one during runtime. Let's say a derived type `class AppPaths2 : AppPaths`.

I can't find the API to do this.

I can use CommentServiceLocator to get an instance of `IComponentContext` but I don't see a way to resolve stuff from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Action<T>` to change the value of your current variable.

```cs
Foo foo = new Foo();
builder.RegisterInstance(foo);
builder.Register<Action<Foo>>(c => newFoo => foo = newFoo);
```

Then, you will be able to change current `Foo` using :

```cs
Action<Foo> fooUpdater = c.Resolve<Action<Foo>>()(); 
fooUpdater(new Foo());
```

You can also use a `FooContainer`.

```cs
class FooContainer
{
    public FooContainer(Foo originalValue)
    {
        this.Value = originalValue;
    }
    public Foo Value { get; set; }
}

// ...

builder.RegisterType<FooContainer>().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<FooContainer>().Value).As<Foo>();

// ...

c.Resolve<FooContainer>().Value = new Foo();
```

Another solution is to update the container :

```cs
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterInstance(new Foo()).AsSelf();
IContainer container = builder.Build();

using (ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    ContainerBuilder updater = new ContainerBuilder();
    updater.RegisterInstance(new Foo()).AsSelf(); // new instance of Foo
    updater.Update(scope.ComponentRegistry);

    scope.Resolve<Foo>(); // ==> new instance of Foo
}
```

But doing so will only add a new registration to the component registry. If you resolve `IEnumerable<Foo>` you will have all your implementations.

Comment: Updating container is the most elegant solution IMHO, ty for this

Comment: @cdie Note that ContainerBuilder.Update() is marked obsolete: "Containers should generally be considered immutable. Register all of your dependencies before building/resolving. If you need to change the contents of a container, you technically should rebuild the container."