# How to update the properties of already registered class in Autofac container in Nunit Framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, nunit, autofac

I use  a dependency injection framework  `AutoFac` in `NUnit` as described 
[here](https://juristr.com/blog/2011/12/writing-ioc-supported-integration-tests/)

The classes are registered as SingleInstance scope.

one of the classes depends on `Setting` class, as given below:

```
    class Product
    {
       public (Setting setting, Dep1 dependency) {....   }
       ....
     }
```

I want to update the properties of one of the classes "Setting"  per test case.

```
 [Test]
 public void Test()
 {

  //Arrange
  var setting = Resolve<Setting>
  Setting.Id = value
  // product depend on two dependency injected via constructor
  var product = Resolve<Product> ; 

  //the problem is: the new values of setting class are not reflected in 
   //Product, and the Product still use the default values provided by the container

    ......        

  }
```

The problem is the updated value is not reflected in the container and unit test fail and the  `Product` class still use the `default values`

I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378919/how-to-register-a-type-with-autofac-after-container-creation), but it can't help.The Documentation of [AutoFac](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html) don't provide guidelines of using in NUnit or test suite.

**The question:** How can I update the values of the class `setting` and the new values are auto injected in the constructor of `product` class in **NUnit**?

Comment: To add to @NightOwl888 , you aren't testing your DI registration or whether the container can resolve instances of the dependencies, you should only be testing your code in the system under test. in reference to your link to the other answer,  your SUT shouldn't care about whether the dependency it needs is a singleton or per-request just mock it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Short Answer

You don't.

### The Long Answer

Each application should have its own [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Since a test project is a separate application from the class under test, you would [never share a production configuration with a test configuration](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/).

When unit testing, you typically don't deal with more than half a dozen or so dependencies at a time. It would be impractical to setup a DI container for this purpose. Instead, you should new up the class under test and mock everything else except for DTO and Model objects.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var setting = new Setting { Value1 = "x", Value2 = "y" };
    var dep1 = new Mock<Dep1>();
    // setup Moq conditions on dep1

    var product = new Product(setting, dep1);

    // Execute method on product and assert
}
```

When integration testing, it is also better to use [pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) than to setup a DI container just for the purpose of testing. However, if you do use a DI container, it should have its own configuration separate from the application that is being tested. Even if this weren't considered a bad practice, there will be dependencies that need to be mocked that warrant this anyway. You are not testing the DI container configuration, you are testing *the components of your application*, so there is no need to make them one and the same.

> **NOTE:** It is strongly advised to use abstractions rather than concrete types as constructor parameters. The usual route is to use interfaces (although I would argue that "settings" might not need to be), but abstract classes will also work.

Comment: Thanks to this guidelines. I was about to refactor a class library and use a separate Di container bez I use  another one  in the composition root of console application that ref this library.
So, you advice me to use pure Di ( a.k.a. Poor Man's DI) and I welcome this approach. Do you advice me to add parameter-less constructor to the classes beside the multi parameter constructor that is used by DI container and continue test using manual DI injection?

Comment: Definitely not. See [Dependency Injection anti-pattern: multiple constructors](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). Each service should only have a single constructor. If you [have too many parameters](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/20/RebuttalConstructorover-injectionanti-pattern/) that is a symptom of another design problem.

Comment: You get it, Great advice. `"An injectable should have a single constructor."`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to update the properties of your `Settings` class, you can create an interface to represent your settings, like

```
public interface ISettings
{
    int Value { get; }
}
```

Inject that interface, not a concrete class, into your `Product` class. Your concrete implementation might read from a configuration file, or you could have an implementation with hard-coded values - whatever you need.

But now that your class depends on that interface, for testing you have a number of options for mocking it.

You could use a test double, like:

```
public class SettingsDouble : ISettings
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Or you could use [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq).

```
var settingsMock = new Mock<ISettings>();
settingsMock.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns(1);
```

A side effect is that your `ISettings` interface and implementations can have read-only properties. Chances are that you don't want classes setting those properties at runtime and affecting other classes' settings, but you made it writable for the purpose of unit testing. Now you don't have to do that.

Comment: `Setting (POCO class)` is a set of properties that Control the logic of generating `product`. My test cases test all alternatives which is controlled by `Setting`.I think there is no need to add interface for it. How can I integrate the mock with Di container that I reference in my question?

Comment: In your test setup you can create an instance of `Settings` and populate it with the values you want. Then, when setting up your container, tell it to return that instance. `builder.Register(c => mySettingsInstance).As<Settings>();` It tells the container to use the one you provided instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I tried it but no change. Can this statement update the container after it was build. Have a look:https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811 and advice me.

Comment: You shouldn't need to update the container. You could also try `builder.RegisterType<Settings>().SingleInstance();` and use that as you did in your original question. That will cause Autofac to always return the same instance of the class. So if you resolve it, get the instance, and set the properties, then the next time it's resolved you'll get the same instance with the properties set. If that doesn't work I'd take a second look at that settings class.

Comment: I have built a demo case in fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/egdABf  ,with your suggestion. The new instance is not reflected in the container.